# how to create following json string in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

how to create following format without nsmutable string?

```
  {
      "appointments" : [
        {
          "pincode" : null,
          "current_status" : "1",
          "initial_status" : "1",
          "hospital_id" : "12",
          "expected_treatment_date" : "18 Nov 2016",
          "appt_comments" : null,
          "lead_followup_by" : "2",
          "speciality_id" : "3",
          "lead_followup_datetime" : "2016-11-17 16:23:17",
          "email" : null,
          "local_id" : 6,
          "mobileno" : "536868868868",
          "enquiry_created_date" : null,
          "id" : "0",
          "enquiry_created_by" : null,
          "state_id" : null,
          "address" : null,
          "fullname" : "googhvvjjc",
          "lead_created_by" : "166",
          "lead_comments" : " H h hh. J",
          "appt_datetime" : null,
          "city_id" : null,
          "other_hospital" : "",
          "cash_credit" : "Cash",
          "create_plan_mail_sent" : "0",
          "interested" : "1",
          "lead_created_date" : "2016-11-17 04:23:24",
          "appt_created_date" : null,
          "appt_created_by" : null
        },
        {
          "pincode" : null,
          "current_status" : "1",
          "initial_status" : "1",
          "hospital_id" : "12",
          "expected_treatment_date" : "18 Nov 2016",
          "appt_comments" : null,
          "lead_followup_by" : "2",
          "speciality_id" : "3",
          "lead_followup_datetime" : "2016-11-17 16:23:17",
          "email" : null,
          "local_id" : 6,
          "mobileno" : "536868868868",
          "enquiry_created_date" : null,
          "id" : "0",
          "enquiry_created_by" : null,
          "state_id" : null,
          "address" : null,
          "fullname" : "googhvvjjc",
          "lead_created_by" : "166",
          "lead_comments" : " H h hh. J",
          "appt_datetime" : null,
          "city_id" : null,
          "other_hospital" : "",
          "cash_credit" : "Cash",
          "create_plan_mail_sent" : "0",
          "interested" : "1",
          "lead_created_date" : "2016-11-17 04:23:24",
          "appt_created_date" : null,
          "appt_created_by" : null
        }
      ],
      "lead_status" : [
        {

        }
      ],
      "lead_followups" : [
        {

        }
      ]
    }
```

My Code :

```
 dicAppointment = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrAppointmentData.count; i++)
    {
        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"rowid"] forKey:@"local_id"];
        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"id"];
        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Fullname"] forKey:@"fullname"];
         [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"email"];

        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"mobileNo"] forKey:@"mobileno"];
        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"date_time"] forKey:@"appt_datetime"];

        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"address"] forKey:@"address"];
        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"cityid"] forKey:@"city_id"];
        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"stateid"] forKey:@"state_id"];
         [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"pincode"] forKey:@"pincode"];
        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"speciality_id"] forKey:@"speciality_id"];


        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"lead_comments"] forKey:@"lead_comments"];
        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"appointment_comment"] forKey:@"appt_comments"];

        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"enquiry_created_date"] forKey:@"enquiry_created_date"];

                  [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"enquiry_created_by"] forKey:@"enquiry_created_by"];

        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"intrested"] forKey:@"interested"];

         [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"lead_follow_by"] forKey:@"lead_followup_by"];

       [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"lead_follow_datetime"] forKey:@"lead_followup_datetime"];

        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"lead_created_date"] forKey:@"lead_created_date"];

         [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"lead_created_by"] forKey:@"lead_created_by"];


         [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"appointment_created_date"] forKey:@"appt_created_date"];

         [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"appointment_created_by"] forKey:@"appt_created_by"];

         [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"initial_status"] forKey:@"initial_status"];

         [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"current_status"] forKey:@"current_status"];

           [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"hospital_id"] forKey:@"hospital_id"];

        [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"cashcredit"] forKey:@"cash_credit"];

         [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"expectdate"] forKey:@"expected_treatment_date"];

           [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"other_hospital"] forKey:@"other_hospital"];

         [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"create_plan_mail_sent"] forKey:@"create_plan_mail_sent"];

    }
```

All three dictionary are same :

now merge the dictionry merge on following dictionary

```
  NSDictionary *d = @{
                    @"appointments": @[ dicAppointment
                            ],@"lead_followups":@[dicleadStatuss],@"lead_status":@[dicleadStatus]

                    };
```

Following code are to covert in json :

```
    NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:d options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);
```

I have successfully converted format but...I can't pass multiple dictionary.

Thanks

Please help me

Comment: in JSON [ ] is the sign of array.

Comment: Do not use `valueForKey:` / `setValue:forKey:` unless you understand and need the KVC functionality. And 50 times getting `arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i`is very very very inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```
"appointments" : [ {},{} ]
```

this is array of Dictionaries, so you need to add your NSDictionary to an Array and then need to convert that array into JSON and pass it to your server.

```
 dicAppointment = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 arrAppointment = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

now at the last of your loop you need to add `dicAppointment` in `arrAppointment`

**Edit**

here you need to pass your array in place of Dictionary

```
 NSDictionary *d = @{ @"appointments":arrAppointment ,@"lead_followups":arrStatus,@"lead_status":arrLeadStatus };
```

Try this

**Edit2**

```
 arrAppointment = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < arrAppointmentData.count; i++)
{
dicAppointment = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"rowid"] forKey:@"local_id"];
    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"id"];
    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Fullname"] forKey:@"fullname"];
     [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"email"];

    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"mobileNo"] forKey:@"mobileno"];
    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"date_time"] forKey:@"appt_datetime"];

    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"address"] forKey:@"address"];
    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"cityid"] forKey:@"city_id"];
    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"stateid"] forKey:@"state_id"];
     [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"pincode"] forKey:@"pincode"];
    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"speciality_id"] forKey:@"speciality_id"];


    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"lead_comments"] forKey:@"lead_comments"];
    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"appointment_comment"] forKey:@"appt_comments"];

    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"enquiry_created_date"] forKey:@"enquiry_created_date"];

              [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"enquiry_created_by"] forKey:@"enquiry_created_by"];

    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"intrested"] forKey:@"interested"];

     [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"lead_follow_by"] forKey:@"lead_followup_by"];

   [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"lead_follow_datetime"] forKey:@"lead_followup_datetime"];

    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"lead_created_date"] forKey:@"lead_created_date"];

     [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"lead_created_by"] forKey:@"lead_created_by"];


     [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"appointment_created_date"] forKey:@"appt_created_date"];

     [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"appointment_created_by"] forKey:@"appt_created_by"];

     [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"initial_status"] forKey:@"initial_status"];

     [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"current_status"] forKey:@"current_status"];

       [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"hospital_id"] forKey:@"hospital_id"];

    [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"cashcredit"] forKey:@"cash_credit"];

     [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"expectdate"] forKey:@"expected_treatment_date"];

       [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"other_hospital"] forKey:@"other_hospital"];

     [dicAppointment setValue:[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"create_plan_mail_sent"] forKey:@"create_plan_mail_sent"];
     [arrAppointment addObject: dicAppointment];
}
```

Comment: can you please convert dictionary to array

Comment: i have added dictionary in my array...but in my dictionary so many values i got only last data in array

Comment: please check my chat

Comment: check array values

Comment: both values are same

Comment: my local_id is diffrent in my array..[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"local_id"] both values are diffrent

Answer (score 0):

I found Another way to do this:

```
NSMutableArray *menuItemNameImage = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arrAppointmentData.count ; i++) {
        [menuItemNameImage addObject: @{
                                        @"local_id" : [[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"rowid"]
                                        ,   @"id" :[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"id"],
                                        @"fullname":[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Fullname"],
                                        @"email":[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"email"],
                                        @"mobileno":[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"mobileNo"],
                                        @"appt_datetime":[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"date_time"],
                                        @"address":[[arrAppointmentData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"address"]
                                        }];
    }
```

Pass your array

```
 NSDictionary *d = @{ @"appointments": menuItemNameImage ,@"lead_followups":arrStatus,@"lead_status":arrLeadStatus };
```